# Failed to call PDFCreator 4.x~5.x com interface in VSTO addin

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, office-addins, pdfcreator

When I  upgrade PDFCreator from version 3.2.0 to the new version one 4.4.1 or 5.0.1.1. My excel VSTO addin can't work(the addin using VB.net VS2019, just call PDFCreator com to print). it works in PDFCreator 3.2.0 with .net Framework 4.5.1, excel 2013 or 2016.
I  compiled my addin again( PDFCreator 4.4.1  with .net Framework 4.7.2), it doesn't work when define "PDFCreatorQueue"(*Dim PDFCreatorQueue As Queue = New Queue*)  and get  err like this:
"ActivationException: No registration for type PdfCreatorAdapter could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. “System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a”

By the way, In windows Forms App, it works good. but it's failed in VSTO addin(I am sure referenced and imported the dll).
Anyone can help? thanks!

I tried change .net Framework,doesn't work. also change debug any CPU/X64/X86.
only works PDFCreator version 3.5 and below.

Comment: It seems there is a problem with PDFCreator configuration. Have you tried contacting PDFCreater vendor/developers instead?

Comment: Yes, but no answer,so I try to find helps here.